# Using a Content Search Web Part to show items from multiple subsites ,that have their status = "Pending" & their Assing-To = "the current login user"

Tags: 2013, web-part, search, configuration, content-search-web-part

I am working on a site collection of type Team Site inside SharePoint server 2013. and i have the following :-

1. The site collection have 10 sub-sites.
2. all the 10 sub-sites were created using the same site template.
3. and each subsite have 2 lists (2 issue tracking lists).

Now I want inside the site collection’s home page to show a general list that display the following info:-

> All the items from all the sub sites’ lists that have "Pending" status & are "Assign-To" the login user.

Now I read about the available options insides SharePoint and I settled on using the content search web part. So i did the following; from the site collection home page>>I edit the page>> I add a content search web part, and I define the following ( Mainly to retrieve only items + under the site collection URL + under the specified list id. but I did not get any result as follow:-

[image]

Now I have these questions:-

1. How I can force the above query to show the items from multiple lists IDs since i will have 20 lists (10 subsites X 2 lists)?
2. How I can filter the items to show only the items that have their Status = Pending and their `Assign-To = ME` (the login user)??

Answer (score 2):

Apart form restricting the Path to current site collection, you need to specify `STS_List_IssueTracking`to get items from Issue Tracking lists only. Moreover, you need to check the managed properties available for Status and Assigned To fields in the Search settings and then use them in the search query. Example:

```
Status:Pending AND AssignedTo:{User.Name}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply so you mean i need to use STS_List_IssueTracking instead of the listIds ?

Comment: `STS_List_IssueTracking` will get data from all Issue Tracking lists. No need to specify them one by one using ListID

Comment: i tried the following "path:"http://servername/ParentsubsiteURL"  
IsDocument:"True" " and i got results from all the subsites under the specifed URL , now i add extra filter as follow "path:"http://servername/ParentsubsiteURL"  
IsDocument:"True" contentclass:"STS_ListItem_IssueTracking" " ,, but this did not return any results , i was expecting that this will show only Issue tracking items ,, can u adivce what could be causing this ?

Comment: Try removing IsDocument:"True". Are you looking for list items or documents?

Comment: @Nadeen you are correct .I specify the following "path:"http://URL/Sites/"  
IsDocument:"False" 
contentclass:"STS_ListItem_IssueTracking" it showed me all the items inside the issue tracking lists, now my real column name is "Risk/Issue status" and not just status . so i wrote the following "path:"http://URL/Sites/"  
IsDocument:"False" 
contentclass:"STS_ListItem_IssueTracking"
Risk/Issue status:Pending" but i did not get any result .. i think the problem is related to referencing the "Risk/Issue status" should i use its display name or internal name ? and should this be encoded ?

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, "Moreover, you need to check the managed properties available for Status and Assigned To fields in the Search settings and then use them in the search query". There is a concept of crawled and managed properties in SharePoint Search. There will be a somewhat similarly named crawled property for your fields. Crawled properties are mapped to managed properties. And finally you need to use the managed property for the field name in the search query

Comment: now all the properties i want to query such as "Risk/Issue status" are site column so these should be included in the crawl is this correct ?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: so i should be able to add this "Risk/Issue status:Pending" to my query ? is this correct ? but this is not working ,,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31183/discussion-between-nadeem-yousuf-and-john-g).

Comment: am also having the same issue, i want to get the list items from task list from all the subsites and where the assigned to  is the current logedin user.i tried with the below : but it  gave me only the current top level site[site collection's] task list only which i dont want.this is my query text is    path:"http://srvr1/sites/EMD"  contentclass:"STS_ListItem_Tasks"
AssignedTo:{User.Name}

Comment: can you pls help how to get teh sub-site's task list items as well?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you put only path in your query so that you get any results. If you get results your search is running ok.

`path:"http://YOURSITE"`

After that you go to desire list/s and click *List Settings*, copy listID from url and decode it from `1aaaaaaa%2Daaaa...` format to format with "-" `1aaaaaaa-aaaa...`

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ - paste id and click decode

After that write in query **`ListID:` contains** not `ListID=` equal

```
path:"http://YOURSITE"
(IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem")
( ListID:1aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa )
```

For more lists put OR in query

```
path:"http://YOURSITE"
(IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem")
( ListID:1aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa )
OR
( ListID:2aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa )
OR
( ListID:... )
```

If you want all lists from content class IssueTracking (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9f87d5d7-08bf-442d-ad3f-91036d164954/content-class-identifier-stslist)
and filter to show only items that have Status=Pending and AssignTo=CurrentUser then your query will look like this:

```
path:"http://YOURSITE"   
contentclass:"STS_ListItem_IssueTracking"
Status:Pending AND AssignedTo:{User.Name}
```

If `Status:Pending` don't return anything, try with `StatusOWSCHCS:Pending` or if you add custom column add that managed property.

**EDIT**

Look in Managed Properties and find that new column

```
http://YOURSITE/_layouts/15/listmanagedproperties.aspx?level=sitecol
```

Something like `RiskIssueStatusOWSCHCS` and add that in query

Comment: thanks a lot for the great reply. now not sure what does content class means ? is it the same as content type? as in my case i am using custom CT which have their parent as the built-in Issue content type. now i try this "path:"http://YOURSITE"  
IsDocument:"True" " and it showed me all item inside my subsite, but when i added the following "contentclass:"STS_ListItem_IssueTracking"
Status:Pending AND AssignedTo:{User.Name}" i did nto get any result ? can you adivce please ?

Comment: try without --> Status:Pending AND AssignedTo:{User.Name}

Comment: list of all contentclass > https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9f87d5d7-08bf-442d-ad3f-91036d164954/content-class-identifier-stslist

Comment: i tried without using "status:Pending AND AssignedTo:{User.Name} " as follow "path:"http://YOURSITE"  
IsDocument:"True" 
contentclass:"STS_ListItem_IssueTracking"" but i did not get any result !!

Comment: try without  contentclass:"STS_ListItem_IssueTracking" and add ListID:aaa... and see if this would return items from that list

Comment: can you adivce why u are including "IsDocuemnt""True" ? i want items not documents ,, should i remove this ?

Comment: You can remove that

Comment: now i start having this working.I specify the following "path:"http://URL/Sites/"  
IsDocument:"False" 
contentclass:"STS_ListItem_IssueTracking" it showed me all the items inside the issue tracking lists, now my real column name is "Risk/Issue status" and not just status . so i wrote the following "path:"http://URL/Sites/"  
IsDocument:"False" 
contentclass:"STS_ListItem_IssueTracking"
Risk/Issue status:Pending" but i did not get any result .. i think the problem is related to referencing the "Risk/Issue status" should i use its display name or internal name ? and should this be encoded ?

Comment: now i have added a custom column named "Risk/Issue status" , so how i can add this to the query ? you mentioned to add a managed property for this column .but as i know that site columns will be manged by the seacth is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a new result source using the content type for the selection of the content to be searched and check to make sure it is returning results from the lists you want. Only then move on to the filtering in the query.

To filter by properties of a column you will need to ensure that the column is mapped to a managed property within the search schema.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219630.aspx

I would suggest focusing on the Assigned to field first as you will note from the above that it is automatically assigned as a managed property.

Then when that is working to filter content properly move on to the Risk/Issue status column which will need to be mapped in the schema before it can be used in the query. Assistance from MS below.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667.aspx